# Special characters in labels Rstudio

Tags: r

I am about to create a boxplot with special characters, unfortunately, I have tried everything, and despite using `labels=c` code, R still does not recognize that I want to use a special character. I know that special characters can be used using e.g. `xlab=expression(paste...`, but this function I have already used to order the columns on the x-axis. Can somebody help, please?

```
boxplot(Atropine2$Heart.Beat ~ Atropine2$Concentration,
boxplot(Atropine2$Heart.Beat ~ Atropine2$Concentration,
col=(c("firebrick3","dodgerblue4")),
main=("Title?"), 
ylab=expression(paste("Heart Beat")), xlab = expression(paste("Concentration")), Atropine2$Concentration <- factor(Atropine2$Concentration, labels=expression("Control", "Atropine 1x10","*-7", "Atropine 1x10-6", "Atropine 1x10-5", "Atropine 1x10-4", "Atropine 1x10-3")))
```

> error: 'factor(Atropine2$Concentration, labels = expression("Control",
> ': invalid 'labels'; length 7 should be 1 or 6

I have been also trying to use "^", "*" to express that I want to use a special character, but still it did not work.

Comment: First: Could you pls give a working minimal example. Second: As the error says, only six labels are needed. Your 'labels' parameter contains seven labels. Third: Did you add {} for the superscript - like "10^{-6}"?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @StefanJelkovich First of all, I am sorry, it is my first time where I am seeking help, usually after loong hours I was able to figure out something by myself. Secondly, Yes, I did use "10^{-6}" and it appears on the x-axis exactly as it is written, without expression of the power function.

Comment: > dput(boxplot(Atropine2$Heart.Beat ~ Atropine2$Concentration,
        col=(c("firebrick3","dodgerblue4")),
        main=("Title"), 
        ylab=expression(paste("Heart Beat")) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("Control", "Atropine 1x10-5")), map_signif_level = TRUE), xlab = expression(paste("Concentration")), Atropine2$Concentration <- factor(Atropine2$Concentration, labels=expression("Control", "Atropine 1x10-7", "Atropine 1x10-6", "Atropine 1x10-5", "Atropine 1x10*{-4}", "Atropine 1x10-3"))))
```